# Disable row after click titanium

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

what I want to do is this: 
I have a tableview and, when I click on a tableviewrow I want this tableviewrow to be disabled so you cannot click it again to fire the event 'click' once again, but I want you to be able to click on any other row from the table.

I've tried this:

```
e.row.touchEnabled = false;
```

But it doesn't seems to work.

Hope you can help me.

Thanks ^.^

Here is the code for the TableView

```
<TableView id="tableBuilding" allowsSelection="true">
                <TableViewRow id="row" selectedBackgroundImage = "/images/bt_select_picker.png">
                    <ImageView id="imgBuilding"/>
                    <Label id="labBuilding" class="labelScroll" text="Building 01" />
                    <ImageView id="imgTransparent6" class="opacity"/>
                    <ImageView id="imgRemove6"  class="remove" onClick="edit"/>
                    <ImageView id="imgHandle6" class="handle" onClick="handle"/>
                </TableViewRow>
                <TableViewRow id="row" selectedBackgroundImage = "/images/bt_select_picker.png">
                    <ImageView id="imgBuilding"/>
                    <Label id="labBuilding" class="labelScroll" text="Building 02" />
                    <ImageView id="imgTransparent7" class="opacity"/>
                    <ImageView id="imgRemove7"  class="remove" onClick="edit"/>
                    <ImageView id="imgHandle7" class="handle" onClick="handle"/>
                </TableViewRow>
                <TableViewRow id="row" selectedBackgroundImage = "/images/bt_select_picker.png">
                    <ImageView id="imgBuilding"/>
                    <Label id="labBuilding" class="labelScroll" text="Building 03" />
                    <ImageView id="imgTransparent8" class="opacity"/>
                    <ImageView id="imgRemove8"  class="remove" onClick="edit"/>
                    <ImageView id="imgHandle8" class="handle" onClick="handle"/>
                </TableViewRow>
                <TableViewRow id="row" selectedBackgroundImage = "/images/bt_select_picker.png">
                    <ImageView id="imgBuilding"/>
                    <Label id="labBuilding" class="labelScroll" text="Building 04" />
                    <ImageView id="imgTransparent9" class="opacity"/>
                    <ImageView id="imgRemove9"  class="remove" onClick="edit"/>
                    <ImageView id="imgHandle9" class="handle" onClick="handle"/>
                </TableViewRow>
                <TableViewRow id="row" selectedBackgroundImage = "/images/bt_select_picker.png">
                    <ImageView id="imgBuilding"/>
                    <Label id="labBuilding" class="labelScroll" text="Building 05" />
                    <ImageView id="imgTransparent10" class="opacity"/>
                    <ImageView id="imgRemove10"  class="remove" onClick="edit"/>
                    <ImageView id="imgHandle10" class="handle" onClick="handle"/>
                </TableViewRow>
            </TableView>
```

And here is te eventListener

```
$.tableBuilding.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.row.children[0].image = "/images/ic_selectedbuilding.png";
    e.row.children[1].color = "white";
    e.row.setTouchEnabled = false;
});
```

Comment: Could you post your code so we could see how the table, table rows, and the event listener is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the tableView is already created use the set method for that propery:

```
e.row.setTouchEnabled = false;
```